# Rblpapi BDH : How do I add a column based on BDH formula and column reference?

Tags: r, bloomberg, blpapi, rblpapi

Im trying to create a column using the RBLPAPI BDH

```
StockMove <- function(ticker){
StockMove <- bdh("MSFT Equity", "Chg_Pct_1D", x$Date, x$Date)
colnames(ernmove) <- NULL
ernmove <- ernmove[,2]

}
```

but I keep getting the error

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : expecting a single value
Called from: bdh_Impl(con, securities, fields, start.date, end.datee, options, overrides, verbose, identity)
```

x$Date is a column of historic dates, and I am trying to create a new column and pull BDH data for each row corresponding to the x$Date column in that row. 
. As a sanity check, I used Sys.Date() in place of the x$Date input and it works correctly.

Thanks for any advice, this is my first question so apologies for any errors.

Comment: check the format of your x$Date? If they are strings, try to convert to Date with as.Date? I know this issue from bdh in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I checked using sapply(x,class) and it appears that the column is indeed date format. Really not sure what to do from here...

Comment: You say xDate is a column of dates. BDH wants a start date and end date. Its not well suited to retrieving a list of dates. And not even one date at a time because holidays have empty data unless you use an override to fill them in. When I want exact dates that I know already, I first retrieve the full range of dates from start to end with BDH, then search for the dates I want.

Answer (score 1):

You say x$Date is a column of dates. BDH wants a start date and end date. I think that's what the error is telling you. You're giving it a column where it wants a single value.

I haven't written any R in forever so forgive me is this is buggy:

```
startDate <- min(x$Date)
endDate <-max(x$Date)
bdh("MSFT Equity", "Chg_Pct_1D", startDate, endDate)
```

BDH is not well suited to retrieving data from a predetermined list of dates. And not even one date at a time, because holidays have empty data unless you use an override to fill them in.

Instead, I always retrieve the full range of dates from start to end with BDH. If I have a column of specific dates that I need, I look them up in that result.

Comment: Correct.  Missed the question two days ago.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. The issue is that im trying to add a column that generates a return for a list of specific dates. So

    GetData[,"ErnMoveVar"] <- Stockmove(ticker)

So I have this list of dates, but this formula doesnt seem to be able to run the BDH 1 day return function for each date in the series. Not sure how else to do this. Thanks again